# Rails Active record order by association and select distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model with a has_many association

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :actions
```

`Action` has a `time` field

I want to write a scope that will give me all the `my_models` distinct with order related to the `first in time action`.

This will give me multiple my_model entries,

```
scope :my_scope, lambda {
    joins(:actions)
      .where.not(actions: { status: :finished })
      .order('actions.time')
      .group(['my_models.id', 'actions.time'])
  }
```

Is it possible to do it on the database level or do I have to do it on rails level?

Comment: There are most likely tons of ways to do this on the database but you're going to need to provide an example of the schema, data and expected result for anyone to want to spend the time taking a crack at it. Don't make us make a bunch of assumptions - the better the picture you can give us the better answers we can give you.

Comment: How about `joins(:actions).where.not(actions: { status: :finished }).group(:id).order(Action.arel_table[:time].minimum.asc)`?